# android create live wallpaper by playing jpg images sequence

Tags: android, android-image, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I am using Rajawali's library for creating a live wallpaper by playing 100 jpg images(as they are doing in their example(I am just replacing their images(from drawable-nodpi)with mine)).But the end results are not what I am expecting like the wallpaper is loading really very late and if I launch any activity and then returns back to the home screen, then it shows only a black screen.And when again I try to set the same wallpaper nothing appears on the home screen(and in order to set this wallpaper again, I first have to set another wallpaper then again my wallpaper).
So,I want to know using rajawali for just jpg image sequence, is it the right approach?
Can anyone guide me with simple reference or tutorial or source code for playing image sequence for making live wallpaper.

Comment: can u put your code and xml please